# Python gpg decryption not printing non english characters correctly

Tags: python

I am trying to decrypt a json message body having mix of numeric and non english characters. The decrypted string is not showing non English characters properly.

Details:-
1) Input is base64 encoded and gpg encrypted
2) I am using python base64 and gnupg modules to decode and decrypt the message.

The output is displayed as (part of the output due to the data sensitivity):-

{"id":"123","name":"ååéåæ¥­é¡

I am expecting the output as 
{{"id":"123","name":"豐國業銀"

Here is the python code I am using for the above task:

```
import json
import os
import base64
import gnupg

gpg = gnupg.GPG()

with open('item2.json', 'r') as file:
     json_data = json.load(file)
     for  value in json_data['items']:
         data  = value['payload']
         print (data)
         str_data = base64.b64decode(data)
         print (str_data)
         decrypted_data = gpg.decrypt(str_data, passphrase=output)
         print (decrypted_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably caused by a character encoding mismatch.  It will also make a difference whether you're using Python 2 or Python 3.

Since Python 2 has finally reached its EOL, I'm going to assume you (and everyone to subsequently read this) need Python 3 code.  There are also a number of possible explanations stemming from the way the `python-gnupg` module accesses the `gpg` executable.

For both security and ease of use reasons, I recommend instead using the Python bindings module which ships whith the [GPGME C API](https://www.gnupg.org/software/gpgme/index.html) instead.

```py
import json
import os
import base64
import gpg

c = gpg.Context(armor=True)

with open('item2.json', 'r') as file:
    json_data = json.load(file)
    for value in json_data['items']:
        data  = value['payload']
        print (data)
        str_data = base64.b64decode(data.encode())
        print (str_data)
        decrypted_data, result, verify_result = c.decrypt(str_data)
        print (decrypted_data)
```

Now `decrypted_data` only contains the plaintext, `result` contains information about the key(s) the encrypted data is encrypted to, and `verify_result` contains information about the key(s) the data was signed with, if any.

More details are in the included documentation, a draft copy is [available here](http://files.au.adversary.org/crypto/gpgme-python-howto.xhtml) for convenience.

In all likelihood, however, the cause was the `base64.b64decoding` method, which needs to process `bytes`, not `str`.  Which means you either need to encode `data` (as I have done above), or read in the JSON data as bytes instead of strings.

Comment: Thanks so much..This helped me to fix the issue i was facing